# "Weekend wakeup" question ideas

Tags: discussion, events

It's been discussed a few times in chat that the huge home-run hitting questions like the vodka one and the toilet one are the perfect thing to fight off the weekend lulls the site suffers from.

This question is about starting an official weekly event to come up with one such question each weekend. It actually includes a few sub questions:

1. We need a good name for the event. We can probably do better than "Weekend wakeup".
2. It might be cool to have a slightly longer slogan as well as a name.
3. Importantly, what time window would be the most effective for bringing people to the site for the longest portion of the weekend possible?

**Please try to address only one point per answer so that people can vote them up/down individually!**

Comment: Great idea to keep the site lively!

Answer (score 5):

For Name:

> **Friday Frenzy!**

- can also be #ff on Twitter which will overlap with #followfriday #ff tags that people use anyway, so may appear on some radars.

Comment: We just need to determine that Friday really is the start of the slump. I guess trying the first one might be a good way (-:

Answer (score 3):

I vote for targetting early Friday morning UTC.  It'll get going then in the UK as peopel get bored at work and hop on twitter and start tweeting or surfing, and will get ready for the US as it kicks in as well.

I realise there's less of an impact then in NZ and Asia etc but I think most people are in the west on this site...I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For **Time**:

[I've asked the Stack Exchange people to provide us with a better idea from their site traffic data exactly when our weekend slump starts and stops.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/dear-stack-exchange-people-could-you-tell-us-our-weekend-slump-time-window) But provide suggestions anyway in case they'd prefer not to divulge such info.

Comment: have a look at http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com - weekend traffic is ~25% - 30% below weekdays.

Answer (score 1):

For **Name**, how about:

> **Weekend Wakeup**

Answer (score 1):

For **Place**:

The easiest solution I could think of is a Google Doc that is more or less public available. I already created a [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/162EfEGOvMS3ckBxqDR-hPBmqwv9xgvlo-iUsn_FPhjk/edit) so that you can start adding questions. I hope no one will abuse it. If this gets a problem we can make the document only privately visible.

Answer (score -1):

In the spirit of alliteration:

For **Name**, how about:

> **Trivial Travel Trifles**

Answer (score -2):

For **Name**, how about:

> **Saturday Stiumulus**